# Limit docker nginx log files size

Tags: docker, nginx, logging

We use the docker image nginx:stable-apline in a docker compose setup:

```
core-nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    restart: always
    environment:
      - NGINX_HOST=${NGINX_HOST}
      - NGINX_PORT=${NGINX_PORT}
      - NGINX_APP_HOST=${NGINX_APP_HOST}
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/conf/dev.template:/tmp/default.template
      - ./log/:/var/log/nginx/
    depends_on:
      - core-app
    command: /bin/sh -c "envsubst '$$NGINX_HOST $$NGINX_PORT $$NGINX_APP_HOST'< /tmp/default.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
    ports:
      - 5001:5001
```

Logfiles are unlimited in size in this setup.

Can anybody provide some pointers how to limit the size of access.log and error.log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways of tackling this problem.

### Docker log driver

The Nginx container you're using, by default, configures the `access.log` to go to `stdout` and the `error.log` to go to `stderr`. If you were to remove the volume you're mounting on `/var/log/nginx`, you would get this default behavior, which means you would be able to manage logs via the Docker log driver. The default [json-file log driver](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/json-file/) has a `max-size` option that would do exactly what you want.

With this solution, you would use the `docker logs` command to inspect the nginx logs.

### Containerized log rotation

If you really want to log to local files instead of using the Docker log driver, you can add a second container to your `docker-compose.yml` that:

- Runs cron
- Periodically calls a script to rename the log files
- Sends an appropriate signal to the `nginx` process

To make all this work:

- The cron container needs access to the nginx logs. Because you're storing the logs on a volume, you can just mount that same volume in the cron container.
- The cron container needs to run in the nginx pid namespace in order to send the restart signal. This is the `--pid=container:...` option to `docker run`, or the `pid:` option in `docker-compose.yml`.

For example, something like this:

```
version: "3"

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./nginx-logs:/var/log/nginx
      - nginx-run:/var/run
    ports:
      - 8080:80

  logrotate:
    image: alpine:3.13
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./nginx-logs:/var/log/nginx
      - nginx-run:/var/run
      - ./cron.d:/etc/periodic/daily
    pid: service:nginx
    command: ["crond", "-f", "-L", "/dev/stdout"]


volumes:
  nginx-run:
```

In `cron.d` in my local directory, I have `rotate-nginx-logs` (mode `0755`) that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

pidfile=/var/run/nginx.pid
logdir=/var/log/nginx

if [ -f "$pidfile" ]; then
    echo "rotating nginx logs"
    for logfile in access error; do
        mv ${logdir}/${logfile}.log ${logdir}/${logfile}.log.old
    done

    kill -HUP $(cat "$pidfile")
fi
```

With this configuration in place, the `logrotate` container will rename the logs once/day and send a `USR1` signal to nginx, causing it to re-open its log files.

---

My preference would in general be for the first solution (gathering logs with Docker and using Docker log driver options to manage log rotation), since it reduces the complexity of the final solution.

Comment: Thanks! First solution worked like a charm!